2D topological insulator, time reversal, and why $\mathbb{Z}_2$? Why not $\mathbb{Z}$?
This is a very naïve question indeed.  I am studying the material from that famous site.
The very first section of the site introduce the idea of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ invariant for zero-dimensional system intuitively as follow: given a Hamiltonian with particle-hole symmetry, we know that its eigenvalues come in pairs of $\pm E$.  As one deform the Hamiltonian, the energy gap can only vanishes when the pair of levels nearest to zero energy cross simultaneously.  The levels can cross and re-cross, and two crossing put the Hamiltonian topologically back to where it was.  Therefore we have a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ index.
And then we move to 1-D spinless Kitaev chain.  Long story short, particle-hole symmetry again attributes gap-closing solely to the two bands nearest to zero energy.  And $\mathbb{Z}_2$ again comes from counting the number of times the two bands nears to zero energy cross zero.
Now onto 2-D, time-reversal invariant, spin-half topological insulator.  My confusions:

Since there is no symmetry requirement that bands come with opposite energies, I fail to see any intuitive reason why gap closing is still a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ affair.

On that note, a uniform chemical potential is perfectly time-reversal symmetric.  It would appear to me that we can have a $2\mathbb{Z}$ invariant that counts the number of filled bands, that cannot change under deformation unless the Hamiltonian becomes gapless along the way.


I've seen Fu and Kane's paper and other references where the Pfaffian is defined.  I can follow the math, but feel zero intuition.  Besides, I don't think the literature discusses my scenario 2, where you just jack up the chemical potential.  What happens to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, for instance?

First of all, in two dimensions, class D, the standard invariant is integer-valued.
In general, you cannot deduce much about these invariants by just looking at the eigenvalues.  Two Hamiltonians can have the same spectrum but have different invariants.  In dimension zero, class D means that in a proper basis the Hamiltonian H is Hermitian and skew-symmetric (so purely imaginary).
Consider the three Hermitian, invertible, skew-symmetric matrices
$$H_{1}=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & i\\
-i & 0 & 0\\
 & 0 & 0 & i\\
 &  & -i & 0
\end{array}\right],\ H_{2}=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & -i\\
i & 0 & 0\\
 & 0 & 0 & -i\\
 &  & i & 0
\end{array}\right],\ H_{3}=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & i\\
-i & 0 & 0\\
 & 0 & 0 & -i\\
 &  & i & 0
\end{array}\right].$$
These all have the same spectrum.  If you fiddle with sines and cosines you can find a continuous path of Hermitian, invertible, skew-symmetric matrices that goes from $H_1$ to $H_2$.  There is no such path from $H_1$ to $H_3$.  To see this, you really need to use the Pfaffian.
The reason you cannot find a $\mathbb{Z}$-valued invariant here is
that if you have two Hamiltonians in this class, $H$ and $K$, then
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
H & 0\\
0 & H
\end{array}\right],\ \left[\begin{array}{cc}
K & 0\\
0 & K
\end{array}\right]
$$
can be connected in the space of invertible, Hermitian, skew-symmetric
matrices.
